# communication between Activity and Service via global data structures?

Tags: android

In an application I have an `Activity`, a `Service` (doing some stuff regardless of whether or not the activity is visible), and a *Model* class (in *MVC* sense), it is a singleton. The activity and the service play the role of *Controllers*, the *View* is defined in the xml layout (nothing custom, the existing classes are re-used). Both *Controllers* use the same *Model*. The service is not remote, that is, lives in the same process.

There are a number of techniques (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686812/communication-between-service-and-activity-on-android), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594936/communication-between-activity-and-service), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508635/communication-approaches-between-activity-and-service-in-android)) recommended for communication between an `Activity` and a `Service`, common data structures are not among them (Google [says](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3) it is possible, but that's in a section that does not even mention broadcasts, messengers, binding and other service-specific stuff). Well, I understand issues with multiple threads, but if I care about the access from multiple threads myself, *why on Earth do I need other methods?*

(UPD: I have checked, in fact, the service and the activity even use the same thread: "main", id=1.)

Question: ***Is the use of common data structures for communication between activities and services considered a bad style? If yes, why?***

So far I am inclined to think that this method is a valid one.

Comment: if both Activity and Service are in the same process use bound local service pattern,  read more here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html then ^F local

Answer (score 0):

Singleton class does the job for me. I'm using a `SingletonActivity` in my projects and never experienced any locking or other thread-specific problems.

The simplicity and transparency of such an approach is way more important than being "bad styled" or soever, and it doesn't introduce any IPC overhead, as the "standard ways" do. Your code remains as clean as YOU want it, and not as Google does >)

Comment: `SingletonActivity`? What is it, what does it do?

Comment: simple extension of `Application` class which holds all needed `session properties` and is used instead of the `Application` in the manifest file